# Problem with STM32F3 custom circuit

Tags: stm32

I designed a board with a stm32F303K8T uC, but I have some strange behaviours. This is not the first board I designed with this uC and I had never any trouble with this design before. The first uC I soldered on this board I could read out with the STUtility tool, but I could not program it. Then I exchanged the uC, but the same thing happened to the second one. What especially seems very strange is, that the PA15 and PB4 on both uC had a constant voltage of around 1.2V applied, which comes somehow from the uC itself and was measured with an oscilloscope. The voltage regulators seem to work fine, and I don't have much ripple on the 3.3V output. When the uC is desoldered, there is no voltage applied at the PA15 and PB4 pins.

Has anyone an Idea what goes wrong here?

[image: microcontroller]
[image: voltage regulators]
[image: sensors]
[image: power electronics]

Edit: I tried to put the capacitor C4 after the inductor, but also this seems not to do any change. The Voltage seems anyway very stable and there was never any voltage drop that could cause a shutdown. I soldered a completely new board, where I only added the STM32, the necessary capacitors and resistors and the voltage regulators, but this leads to the exactly same problem. I don't get also why PA15 and PB4 are high when the STM32 is not programmed, this isn't normal, right?

Further here is my layout: [image: Layout]

Comment: The LC low pass on VDDA be exactly the other way around: C close to the µC, L in series with the supply voltage! the way you do this, you're shielding your power supply from noise energy flowing out of the VDDA pin, not the other way around. You might want to watch what the oscilloscope says about the voltage at the VDDA pin. As for VDD1 and VDD2: this is but a schematic, but you'd usually draw it so that each VDD1 and VDD2 have their "own" cap, close as possible to that pin (I hope your layout does exactly that).

Comment: (I say that because I had smaller STM32 black out due to insufficient VDDA supplies!) Regarding your power supply design overall: Using a "low dropout regulator" to go from 12 V to 3.3 V is not really necessary :) you're wasting 434 mW on that, and that will, depending on the case variant, probably heat up the LM2937 by at least 25 K. Do you need the 12V elsewhere? If not, why not directly regulate down to let's say 6V and then use an actual LDO?

Comment: Hi, The 12V are used for a RF Transceiver, otherwise I would have gone directly to 3.3V. I have the 100nF caps directly next to the VDD pins, so this should not cause the issue. About the VDDA, I really did a mistake there, but do you think that's enough for such a strange behaviour?

Comment: I'd really probe around with an oscope, or, for a quick check, actually desolder C4 and replace it with a wired ceramic 100 nF capacitor between the pin side of L2 and ground. As said, I did have my own STM32 black out because VDDA wasn't working well enough, so yeah, I recon that might be at least a contributing factor!

Comment: Also consider input leakage &  ESD diodes and 10M load on probe. Are you ESD safe?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this thread because I had the same problem and I managed to solve it, at least on my side. I know this answer is probably too late to be useful for you, but for the sake of the future:
those two pins (PA15 and PB4) don't work because their reset state is alternate function (where they work as JTAG pins). So you need to reset their MODER and PUPDR registers (they also have pullups by default). See RM0313 pg. 151.